# Can the radial blur zoom outwards not inwards?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

How do you create the effect in photoshop to make shapes appear to shoot **out** from the center of an image, a bit like light rays.

Radial blur with zoom seems to blur both out from the center *and* towards to the center (the effect you would see if you were moving in relation to an object). This is close but ultimately isn't the effect i'm after

[image: attached image of the radial blur effect]

(attached image of the radial blur effect:)

Comment: i'll attach a better image when i get a chance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Free Transform (ctrl+t on pc). Set the transform centerpoint to the radial blur centerpoint, hold down shift to keep proportions and alt to resize all four sides at the same time, and drag the start of the blur to match the object.

If you're worried about lowering the render quality while scaling bigger you could do the radial blur with bigger resolution in a different file, but scaling blurs is relatively safe qualitywise.

Heres a screenie:

[image: How to Radial Blur only Out or Inwards]

Comment: great, i actually just came back to this problem today and found a similar solution. works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Here's an interesting fact, radial blur has a different effect depend on where on the page the object is that you are using the filter on. This is because it is based form the center, and works in a circular way, hence: radial blur.

Also, out of curiosity, the attached image is or is not what you are going for?

Comment: not what i'm going for, i want it to only blur the object outwards from the center. but by default it is also blurring *inwards* towards the center

Comment: Hmm, despite it's tediousness, you may be best off masking. I'll put some more creative thought it into tomorrow, but that's all I got on my tired brain at the moment :]

Answer (score 0):

I would think the clever use of layers and masks would resolve this. Just add the blur effect on a different layer and mask out the parts you don't want. It will probably take a bit of trial and error to get the exact effect you want, but the Radial Blur tool is a fairly blunt instrument.

Comment: i think this would be very difficult/tedious to do since some parts are blurred over the top of others...